# How does BibTeX sort references?

Tags: bibtex, sorting

How does LaTeX sort references as it is causing the first reference I have used to be numbered as [2] in the document rather than [1]. See below:

> Technology has been introduced in various ways within healthcare applications to support the delivery of reminders [2]. One of the most prevalent approaches to date for the delivery of reminders has been through the use of mobile phones, especially within the domain of provision of support for persons with dementia [1, 3].

Ref [2] in this paragraph is the first reference in my `.bib` file, how can I get it to be shown as [1]?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

Technology has been introduced in various ways within healthcare applications to support the delivery of reminders \cite{GatorTechSmartHouse}. One of the most prevalent appraches to date for the delivery of reminders has been through the use of mobile phones, especially within the domain of provision support for persons with dementia \cite{NextGenerationOfMobileMedicationManagementSolutions, VideoRemindersAsCognitiveProstheticsForPeopleWithDementia}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

`.bib` file

```
@article{
GatorTechSmartHouse,
    Author = {S. Helal, W. Mann, H. El-Zabadani, J.King, Y. Kaddoura, E. Jansen},
    Title = {The {G}ator {T}ech {S}mart {H}ouse: a programmable pervasive space},
    Journal = {Computer},
    Volume = {38, No. 3},
    Pages = {50-60},
    Year = {2001}
}

@article{
NextGenerationOfMobileMedicationManagementSolutions,
    Author = {C.D. Nugent, D. Finlay, R. Davis, M. Mulvenna, J. Wallace, C. Paggetti, E. Tamburini, N. Black},
    Title = {The next generation of mobile medication management solutions},
    Journal = {International {J}ournal of {E}lectronic {H}ealthcare},
    Volume = {3, No. 1},
    Pages = {7-31},
    Year = {2007}
}

@article{
VideoRemindersAsCognitiveProstheticsForPeopleWithDementia,
    Author = {S. O'Neill, S. Manson, G. Parente, M.P. Donnelly, C.D. Nugent, S. McClean, B. Scotney, D. Craig},
    Title = {Video reminders as cognitive prosthetics for people with dementia},
    Journal = {Ageing {I}nternational},
    Volume = {36, No. 2},
    Pages = {267-282},
    Year = {2011}
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you need the bibliography sorted in order of appearance, use

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

because the `plain` bib style sorts alphabetically by author.

---

As an aside: your bib entries are wrong. Authors should be separated by `and` rather than commas:

```
@article{
GatorTechSmartHouse,
    Author = {S. Helal and W. Mann and H. El-Zabadani and J. King and Y. Kaddoura and E. Jansen},
    Title = {The {Gator} {Tech} {Smart} {House}: a programmable pervasive space},
    Journal = {Computer},
    Volume = {38, No. 3},
    Pages = {50-60},
    Year = {2001}
}
```

Watch out for missing spaces between name (initials) and surname.

Also it's better to write `{Tech}` for keeping the uppercase, so kerning between `T` and `e` can be applied (which isn't if the input is `{T}ech`).

Comment: Thanks for that, as well as the other info. I was following a PDF I found on creating references which didn't mention those extra points, so thanks!

Comment: +1 for kerning alert; elsewhere the converse is (ignorantly) proposed, good to know...

Comment: How to do this when I need to use an existing bibliography style (but can modify it)? (so I can't just use `unsrt`)

Comment: @HendyIrawan If you *have* to use a specific bib style, why would you want to change its choices about sorting?

Comment: @egreg a few possible reasons. For my purpose it was because of a "bug" in the style. Another reason is to create a style similar to an existing one but with some modifications. Some journals/proceedings use a style but with their own little overriding rules.

Comment: @HendyIrawan The real answer would be “use `biblatex`”. Modifying existing BibTeX style is always a nightmare.

Comment: @egreg it's an alternative, but I am almost perfectly happy with the given bibtex style except for the sorting.

Comment: @HendyIrawan Open a new question with the details