# IEEEtran: How to get rid of ordering in bibtex

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51434/biblatex-citation-order)'s answer is addressed how to get rid of the ordering via `sorting=none` option of `biblatex` package.

How can I acquire the same result with `bibtex` without calling `biblatex`?

I'd just tried to add `\nocite{*}` just after `\begin{document}`, but it changed nothing.

---

**Update 1**:`MWE`

```
%% bare_conf.tex
%% V1.4b
%% 2015/08/26
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\title{XXX}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{XXX}
\IEEEauthorblockA{YYY
Email: ZZZ}
}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
The abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}

Highly complex systems are typically composed many components. A system configuration (mode) is a particular collective behavior exhibited from a specific subset of the system's components. Reconfiguration Desirability in case of complex systems is two-fold: reconfiguration firstly paves the way for realizing multimodal systems, thereby achieving multifunctionality through multimodality. Furthermore, the complex system's resilience against (fatal) faults is increased; because, reconfiguration facilitates the switching from the faulty configuration to another functional configuration.

There have been extensive investigations on the notion of reconfiguration in view of different complex systems such as power systems ( \cite{abdelaziz2010distribution,gomes2006new,mcdermott1999heuristic,sarfi1996distribution}), embedded systems (\cite{voros2009dynamic,van2016model}), hybrid systems (\cite{riverso2016plug,momayyezan2016integrated,wang2016highly}), and manufacturing systems (\cite{ohashi2001model,sanderson2016smart,farid2017measures}).

Some efforts have been also applied to engineer reconfigurable DESs. As an instance, \cite{zhang2015reconfigurable} recommended a coordinated approach to solve the problem. The aforesaid technique stressed mainly on communicational issues among subsystems. Furthermore, it assumes all subsystems equipped with coordinators, which handles the reconfigurations of the system. Moreover, the technique is not computationally scalable; since the dimensions of the considered non-sparse matrices are intractably increased in real complex systems.

\section{Preliminaries}
Supervisory Control Theory \cite{wonham2017supervisory} governs the control of DESs according to the Ramadge-Wonham model \cite{ramadge1987supervisory,wonham2015supervisory}. A DES is formally represented by a generator, say

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references}{}

\end{document}
```

And the `.bib` file:

```
@article{wonham2015supervisory,
  title={Supervisory control of discrete-event systems},
  author={Wonham, W Murray},
  journal={Encyclopedia of Systems and Control},
  pages={1396--1404},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@misc{wonham2017supervisory,
    author = {Wonham, W Murray},
    title = {Supervisory Control of Discrete Event Systems},
    howpublished = {Sys. Control Group, ECE Dept., Univ. of Toronto, Toronto, ON, Canada},
    year={2017 [Online]. Available: http://www.control.toronto.edu/DES/}.
}

@article{ramadge1987supervisory,
    title={Supervisory control of a class of discrete event processes},
    author={Ramadge, Peter J and Wonham, W Murray},
    journal={SIAM journal on control and optimization},
    volume={25},
    number={1},
    pages={206--230},
    year={1987},
    publisher={SIAM}
}

@article{abdelaziz2010distribution,
    title={Distribution system reconfiguration using a modified Tabu Search algorithm},
    author={Abdelaziz, Almoataz Youssef and Mohamed, FM and Mekhamer, SF and Badr, MAL},
    journal={Electric Power Systems Research},
    volume={80},
    number={8},
    pages={943--953},
    year={2010},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{gomes2006new,
    title={A new distribution system reconfiguration approach using optimum power flow and sensitivity analysis for loss reduction},
    author={Gomes, Fl{\'a}vio Vanderson and Carneiro, Sandoval and Pereira, Jose Luiz R and Vinagre, Marcio Pinho and Garcia, Paulo Augusto Nepomuceno and De Araujo, Leandro Ramos},
    journal={IEEE Transactions on Power Systems},
    volume={21},
    number={4},
    pages={1616--1623},
    year={2006},
    publisher={IEEE}
}

@article{mcdermott1999heuristic,
    title={A heuristic nonlinear constructive method for distribution system reconfiguration},
    author={McDermott, Tom E and Drezga, Irislav and Broadwater, Robert P},
    journal={IEEE Transactions on Power Systems},
    volume={14},
    number={2},
    pages={478--483},
    year={1999},
    publisher={IEEE}
}

@article{sarfi1996distribution,
    title={Distribution system reconfiguration for loss reduction: an algorithm based on network partitioning theory},
    author={Sarfi, RJ and Salama, MMA and Chikhani, AY},
    journal={IEEE Transactions on Power Systems},
    volume={11},
    number={1},
    pages={504--510},
    year={1996},
    publisher={IEEE}
}

@book{voros2009dynamic,
    title={Dynamic System Reconfiguration in Heterogeneous Platforms: The MORPHEUS Approach},
    author={Voros, Nikolaos and Rosti, Alberto and H{\"u}bner, Michael},
    volume={40},
    year={2009},
    publisher={Springer Science \& Business Media}
}

@article{riverso2016plug,
    title={Plug-and-play fault detection and control-reconfiguration for a class of nonlinear large-scale constrained systems},
    author={Riverso, Stefano and Boem, Francesca and Ferrari-Trecate, Giancarlo and Parisini, Thomas},
    journal={IEEE Transactions on Automatic Control},
    volume={61},
    number={12},
    pages={3963--3978},
    year={2016},
    publisher={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{ohashi2001model,
    title={Model-based control for reconfigurable manufacturing systems},
    author={Ohashi, Kazushi and Shin, Kang G},
    booktitle={Robotics and Automation, 2001. Proceedings 2001 ICRA. IEEE International Conference on},
    volume={1},
    pages={553--558},
    year={2001},
    organization={IEEE}
}

@article{zhang2015reconfigurable,
    title={Reconfigurable coordination of distributed discrete event control systems},
    author={Zhang, Jiafeng and Khalgui, Mohamed and Li, Zhiwu and Frey, Georg and Mosbahi, Olfa and Salah, Hela Ben},
    journal={IEEE Transactions on Control Systems Technology},
    volume={23},
    number={1},
    pages={323--330},
    year={2015},
    publisher={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{sanderson2016smart,
    title={Smart Manufacturing and Reconfigurable Technologies: Towards an Integrated Environment for Evolvable Assembly Systems},
    author={Sanderson, David and Chaplin, Jack C and De Silva, Lavindra and Holmes, Paul and Ratchev, Svetan},
    booktitle={Foundations and Applications of Self* Systems, IEEE International Workshops on},
    pages={263--264},
    year={2016},
    organization={IEEE}
}

@article{farid2017measures,
    title={Measures of reconfigurability and its key characteristics in intelligent manufacturing systems},
    author={Farid, Amro M},
    journal={Journal of Intelligent Manufacturing},
    volume={28},
    number={2},
    pages={353--369},
    year={2017},
    publisher={Springer}
}

@article{momayyezan2016integrated,
    title={Integrated Reconfigurable Configuration for Battery/Ultracapacitor Hybrid Energy Storage Systems},
    author={Momayyezan, Milad and Abeywardana, Damith B Wickramasinghe and Hredzak, Branislav and Agelidis, Vassilios G},
    journal={IEEE Transactions on Energy Conversion},
    volume={31},
    number={4},
    pages={1583--1590},
    year={2016},
    publisher={IEEE}
}

@article{wang2016highly,
    title={A highly integrated and reconfigurable microgrid testbed with hybrid distributed energy sources},
    author={Wang, Chengshan and Yang, Xianshen and Wu, Zhen and Che, Yanbo and Guo, Li and Zhang, Shuhuai and Liu, Yixin},
    journal={IEEE Transactions on Smart Grid},
    volume={7},
    number={1},
    pages={451--459},
    year={2016},
    publisher={IEEE}
}

@incollection{van2016model,
    title={Model-Based Engineering of Runtime Reconfigurable Networked Embedded Systems},
    author={van Leeuwen, Coen and Rieter-Barrell, Yolanda and Papp, Zoltan and Pruteanu, Andrei and Vogel, Teus},
    booktitle={Runtime Reconfiguration in Networked Embedded Systems},
    pages={1--28},
    year={2016},
    publisher={Springer}
}
```

**Update 2**: Deleting `nocite{*}` changes nothing.

Comment: **Googling** `bibtex no sorting` leads to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112816 (`\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: The entries are still sorted. Please check the update.

Comment: Are you trying to write an IEEE paper and want to submit it? If yes, have you had a look at the information about bibliography provided by IEEE? For example `IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf` which among other stuff contains `IEEEtran.bst: The standard IEEEtran BIBTEX style file
(unsorted, i.e., references will appear in the order in which
they are cited).`

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: Deleting `nocite:{*}` changed nothing (Update 2).

Comment: your bib file gives an error: I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 14 of file references.bib
 :     year={2017 [Online]. Available: http://www.control.toronto.edu/DES/}

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: It's strange because I can compile it by `bibtex` correctly. Maybe I better delete everything and work with new files!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear what you mean by "unordered" bibtex has two orderings order in order of citation (most bibtext styles that so this are called unsorted so I guess this is what you want?) or order in alphabetical order (usually of author)

If I delete the spurious `.` in the bib file entry for wonham2017supervisory
then the entries are numbered in order of citation resulting in the references here being in increasing numeric order as expected.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this prevented a correct BiBTeX run and the changes in the code never were executed.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to help if you provide a clean and simple MWE. As I mentioned in my comment, I think that you maybe need to use an IEEE-specific BiBTeX style (e. g. `IEEEtran.bst`).

> **IEEEtran.bst:** The standard IEEEtran BIBTEX style file (**unsorted**, i.e.,
>   references will appear in the order in which they are cited).

---

> Before you try the solution, delete all the generated files as marked
>   in the screenshot.

[image]

> If you still have trouble, then I would start with my code and would
>   add piece by piece your code up to the point where there is a problem.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{cite}

\begin{filecontents}{myBib.bib}
@article{paper01,
  title={Titel 1},
  author={Auther One},
}
@article{paper02,
  title={Titel 2},
  author={Auther Two},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\title{XXX}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{XXX}
\IEEEauthorblockA{YYY
Email: ZZZ}
}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
The abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}

\cite{paper02}
\cite{paper01}

\section{Preliminaries}

%% IEEEtran OR unsrt
%\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{myBib}

\end{document}
```

### `unsrt`

[image]

### `IEEEtran`

[image]

### `IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf`

[image]

Comment: Your `MWE` does not use `IEEETran.bst`. As I call it in coordination with `unsrt`, the result is sorted.

Comment: You did not reply to my question/comment about `IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf`.  I did not know what you want. Nevertheless, my code gives the desired output for both, `IEEEtran` and `unsrt` on my system.

Comment: The answer to your comment: "I had already read it. As my problem was not resolved, I sent this question." `Your answer has not solved my problem`, by the way.

Comment: The current question is *to get rid of the ordering* (like here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51434/), I do not understand what part of the question is not solved at the moment.

Comment: Nothing is solved. Because I applied what you said to my file, and the result is still ordered. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: **(1)** Is your file different from the code that you provide in your question? **(2)** Have you tried to delete all generated files? --> See update.

Comment: (1) The file is exactly the same as my `MWE`. (2) Yes.

Comment: Then I would start with *my* code and would add piece by piece *your* code up to the point where there is a problem. @David Carlisle will have found the problem.